# Can every Hausdorff topological space be homeomorphically embedded in a topological vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

It's true that for any metric space, we can isometrically embed it in a Banach space, so that the image of the metric space by that embedding is a linearly independent set.

Is the analogous theorem for topological spaces true? Often topological vector spaces are required to be Hausdorff, so with that definition the theorem could only potentially be true for topological spaces which are also Hausdorff.

So, to make it clear what I mean, rephrasing the title. Given a topological space $ (X, \tau) $ is it possible to find a topological vector space $ V $ and an embedding (homeomorphic onto the image) $ f:X \rightarrow  V $ such that $ f(X) $ is a linearly independent subset of $ V $? Or can we at least somehow weaken this statement to make it true?

Comment: A homeomorphism can't have a linearly independent image unless the vector space is trivial. Also, a homeomorphism exists if and only if $X$ can be made into a topological vector space.

Comment: @MattSamuel He's talking about *embeddings*,  continuous injections that induce a homeomorphism onto their image.

Comment: My mistake, I was typing in a hurry and incorrectly called f a homeomorphin between X and V, instead of X and f(X)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any completely regular (Hausdorff) topological space can be imbedded in $\mathbb{R}^J$ for some index set $J$, which is a topological vector space. Indeed, this is true if and only if a topological space is completely regular. Thus any Hausdorff topological space that is not completely regular cannot be imbedded in a topological vector space over the reals.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you also give me a reference where I could find more about this theorem, preferably with a proof?

Comment: @Ormi I know it from "Topology" by Munkres.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:

Matt Samuel's comment isn't quite true: here's an embedding (=map which is a homeomorphism onto its image) of $[0, 1]$ into a topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, whose image is linearly independent:

The space is $V=\prod_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{R}$ - elements of $V$ are maps $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with addition and scalar multiplication defined in the obvious way.

The embedding is given by the following. For a real $r$, let $[\cdot]_r: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function such that if $s\le r$, then $[s]_r=r-s$, and if $s>r$ then $[s]_r=0$. Our embedding, then, is the following:

$$x\mapsto "y\mapsto [y]_x."$$

It's easily checked that this is a topological embedding, and that its image is a linearly independent subset of $V$.

Comment: Embeddings can certainly be linearly independent. Not homeomorphisms.